# Apache loading queue problems

Tags: apache, apache-config, httpd.conf

I now have 8GB of ram in my server, so bare that in-mind when making recommendations on how much to up settings.

Basically, Apache won't concurrently load more than one page at a time. What the hell could be causing this? This causes real problems when I execute a page that takes a long time to load, no other pages will load.

Total idiot here, so advice desperately needed!

Thanks guys, must be something quite simple.

Comment: This looks like it should be a http://serverfault.com/ question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved, changed memory usage in scripts.